# The next palindrome code

Tags: c

The problem is to find the first palindrome number which is greater than 
the number entered by the user.

In fact, my code is giving the correct output for all the test cases that I have tried. But I am getting the wrong answer on spoj. I have also checked that no blank spaces or extra lines are being printed. I have tried 808, 2133, 1, 999 and many more as input.

What should I do? Here follows my code. Moreover it is not crossing the time limit.

```
#include<stdio.h>


void palindrome(int n)
{
  int array[10],len,temp,i ; 
  temp = n;
  len = 0 ; 
  while(temp!=0)
  {
    array[len] = temp%10;
    len++;
    temp = temp/10;
  }

  //when the number is of the form 99,999,9999  and so on
  for(i=0;i<len;i++)
  {
    if(array[i]!=9)
    break;
  }
  if(i==len)
  {
    printf("%d",n+2);
    return ;
  } 


  if((len%2)==1)
  {
  //when the length is odd 0,1,2,3,4 and it does not consist of all 9s.
     for(i=0;i<(len/2);i++)
     {
       array[i] = array[len-1-i];
     }
     //at this stage we again check if number is already of the form 9,99 999 or so on
     for(i=0;i<len;i++)
     {
        if(array[i]!=9)
        break;
     }
     if(i==len)
     {
        for(i=0;i<len;i++)
        printf("%d",array[len-1-i]);
        return ;  
     }
     // if the number is not of the form 9 ,99 ,999 then
     i=0;
     while((array[(len/2)-i]==9)&&(i<=(len/2)))
     {
        array[len/2-i] = 0;
        array[len-1-len/2+i] = 0 ;
        i++;
     }
     array[len/2-i] = array[len/2-i] +1 ;
     array[len-1-len/2+i] = array[len/2-i] ;   
     for(i=0;i<len;i++)
     printf("%d",array[len-1-i]);
     return ; 
  }

  //if the len is even eg 6 ,  0,1,2,3,4,5 6/2 = 3 
  for(i=0;i<len/2-1;i++)
  {
    array[i] = array[len-1-i];
  }
  if(array[len/2]!=9)
  {
    array[len/2-1] =  array[len/2]+1 ; 
    array[len/2] = array[len/2-1] ; 
    for(i=0;i<len;i++)
     printf("%d",array[len-1-i]);
     return ; 
  }
   //at this stage we again check if number is already of the form 99999 or 999 or so on
     for(i=0;i<len;i++)
     {
        if(array[i]!=9)
        break;
     }
     if(i==len)
     {
        for(i=0;i<len;i++)
        printf("%d",array[len-1-i]);
        return ;  

     }
    i=0;
    while(array[len/2-i-1]==9)
    {
      array[len/2-i-1] = 0;
      array[len+i-len/2] = 0; 
      i++;
    }
    array[len/2-i-1] = array[len/2-i-1] +1;
    array[len+i-len/2] = array[len/2-i-1];
    for(i=0;i<len;i++)
     printf("%d",array[len-1-i]);
     return ; 
}


int main()
{ 
  int n,t,i;
  scanf("%d",&t);
  for(i=0;i<t;i++)
  {
    scanf("%d",&n);
    palindrome(n);
    printf("\n");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: your code when input `100`, result is `111`, not `101`.

Answer (score 2):

Palindrome work is quite simple.  It consists of a mirroring phase, and then one check to see if the mirror is greater than the actual number.  If it is not, then we add the middle value and re-mirror.  Here is the code that performs exactly that.  You may need some minor refactorization to fit your exact needs, but this should get you right along the path to completion.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int palindrome(int n);
int mirror(int n);

int main(void) {
  int num;
  num = palindrome(4549534);
  printf("%d\n", num);
  return 0;
}

int palindrome(int n) {
  int array[10],len,temp,new_num,odd_digits,limit;
  len = 0;
  temp = n;
  while (temp!=0) {
    array[len] = temp%10;
    len++;
    temp = temp/10;
  }

  // These values are needed outside of the mirror function.                                                                          
  // Good code style would make these class values.                                                                                   
  odd_digits = (len % 2);
  limit = len / 2 + odd_digits;
  new_num = mirror(n);

  if (new_num < n) {
    // Palindromes increase from the middle.                                                                                          
    new_num += (int) pow(10, limit - 1);
    // Re-mirror the number.                                                                                                          
    new_num = mirror(new_num);
  }

  return new_num;
}

int mirror (int n) {
  int array[10],len,temp,i,new_num,odd_digits,limit,top,bottom ;
  temp = n;
  new_num = 0;
  len = 0 ;
  temp = n;
  while (temp!=0) {
    array[len] = temp%10;
    len++;
    temp = temp/10;
  }

  odd_digits = (len % 2);
  limit = len / 2 + odd_digits;

  for (i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
    top = array[(len - 1) - i] * (int) pow(10,((len - 1) - i));
    bottom = array[(len - 1) - i] * (int) pow(10, i);
    // Check to see if this is the middle term, in which case we only need to                                                         
    // add one value.                                                                                                                 
    if ((len - 1 - i) == i) {
      bottom = 0;
    }
    new_num += top + bottom;
  }

  return new_num;
}
```